# Bookdown book into PDF for offline reading

Tags: bookdown

Can I convert a Bookdown book into a single PDF file so that I can access it when I am offline?

I specifically have this book in mind:
https://bookdown.org/wfoote01/faur/

Answer (score 0):

Just google the title of the book, then you can find a [PDF](https://turing.manhattan.edu/~wfoote01/finalytics/_site/PDF/BOOK-Financial_Analytics.pdf)...